# 2008 Jeep Grand Cherokee Trans over temp

Tags: transmission, jeep, cel, temperature, grand-cherokee

Red Lightning bolt, engine light, trans over temp, occasionally problems with starting.

About 3 weeks ago, one day I started my car, (it was cold) and I dint wait for it to warm up like I usually would. I was in a rush and I drove to the store around the corner. About 5 mins after my car was started, a red lightening bolt appeared on my dash and the temperature gauge was stuck on cold. I replaced the thermostat. I looked into the lightening bolt symbol and I've come to the assumption that I need to put one of those fuel cleaners in my tank. I haven't done so yet, because about 2 weeks ago, I was getting gas and when I went to start my car afterwards, it wouldn't start. I gave it about 15 minutes and was able to start it, however it wasn't running right (shaking, not sounding 'alive') so I parked it in the back of the gas station and a few days later it was determined that I needed a new battery. so I replaced the battery, it runs good, however I'm still having problems with the lights and I'm now getting a light saying trans over temp. The temp gauge shoots to hot after about 10 minutes of driving it. It gets a little smoky but I don't drive it after I see it getting too hot. And I haven't driven it at all in the past few days because I'm afraid to further damage it.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What *exactly* is your question? Is it you are trying to figure out why the trans is going over temp? Have you viewed what codes might be present in the ECU? If so, what are they?

Comment: When I read the vehicle, no codes are coming back. I'm trying to find out what the problem could possibly be.